# Bluemix Git connect to Git Desktop

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created a new project in Bluemix with a Text to Speech Service. I added a toolchain with a new Git Repo. I have created a key on the computer and copied that key into the Bluemix RepositoryDeploy Keys section.

When I go to the computer Git Desktop I get an authentication error. I have tried everything and can't get it to authenticate.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message that you are seeing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I used to import a GitLab repository into GitHub Desktop:

1. [Set up git authentication](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/git_working.html#git_authentication) with [SSH](https://git.ng.bluemix.net/profile/keys) (I had trouble getting this to work with HTTPs -- kept getting *Failed authentication* errors). To generate a key, follow the instructions [here](https://git.ng.bluemix.net/help/ssh/README).
2. Clone the repository using the git cli (`git clone git@git.ng.bluemix.net:...`)
3. Add to GitHub Desktop by going *File* > *Add Local Repository*
4. Finally, after making a change, I was able to sync the repository and push the changes up

---

I got a gpg error when I ran it for the first time and found this solution to solve that (you may / may not run into this):

```
git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg)
```

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/675